# Dynamic Parameter panel load

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular2 and I am stuck in implementing one of the scenario.

I am building one Job which can have multiple tasks inside it.

so my first component is jobcomponent which create Task Modal Form

Now when my Task Modal form is open it has a TaskType select control and it has multiple Tasks Type loaded from m service:

```
enter code here

TaskType {
TaskName:Run process
[TaskParameters] : { Name :Batch File Name, InputType:Text ,IsRequired :True }
                   { Name :Batch argument, InputType:Text ,IsRequired :True }
},
TaskType {
TaskName:Send Email
[TaskParameters] : { Name :SMTP, InputType:Text ,IsRequired :True }
                   { Name :RECEPIENTS, InputType:Text ,IsRequired :false}
}

enter code here
```

So Depending upon the TaskType user choose from the parent Select dropdown I need to dynamically create a Parameters panel as per the above structure and all the properties of the Parameters are updated as per the user entry value in the panel.

Once user clicks on Create Task button the TaskObject with all parameters value entered by the user is added to Tasks[] array of NewJob object and when user clicks on SaveJob button the NewJob object is submitted to the server side.

Can anybody help me setting up a sample code snippet for my requirement.

Thanks in advance ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this : I have done 2 steps to accomplish this above task

1) Load all the Tasks in first dropdown
2) On change of the dropdown I do a filter and get all the parameters for the selected Task
3) I have also made a dynamic form component where each component having one textbox control in it and the formControlName is a dynamic id
4) On step 2 on change event : I have assigned the FormGroup with all the Dynamic parameter id (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)
5) Now i can see all the parameters for the selected Task is populated.

While doing this one challenge I am facing is the Label text is appearing with a delay of 1 second for each textbox control.

I am not sure where I am doing some mistake and why the label text is slowly appearing for each textbox control on the dynamic form.

Can anyone help me resolving this issue.